# Set div height in CSS based on website height (not viewport height)

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I am using Wordpress and I have set up a website using a website builder that has multiple divs that expand the full width of the screen. I want to draw a vertical line across the left side that starts 300px from the top and 100px from the left and extends to the bottom of the web page (not the viewport height).

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoi1x.png)

The solution I found so far is to add a div to the very top and with css draw the line from the starting position, while increasing the size of the div to match the height of the page, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNlmM.png)

The challenge I'm facing now is how do I extend the div box to have the height of the page? It seems it's not possible with CSS alone, but I also haven't been getting far with Javascript either. The ideas I've had are to return the scrollHeight and pass into into a style tag in the HTML div tag, but I haven't been able to get it working either.

Below my CSS/HTML code:

**CSS/HTML**

```css
    static {
         float: left;
         overflow: hidden;
         position: absolute;
         flex-direction: column;
         left: 100px;
         top: 300px;
         min-height: 100vh;
         height: auto;
         border-left: 1px solid green; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="static" id="line"></div>
```

Thanks!

---

#EDIT#

Thanks for the feedback! I tried the solutions set out, but unfortunately they didn't work for my specific case. It seems as though the Wordpress Theme I am using is causing issues.

Nonetheless, I found a workaround. It's not beautiful, but maybe it can help somebody in the future.

The issue is that I cannot wrap the divs in the page in another div. The Wordpress page builder theme I am using sets divs within it's own system, [so I needed to get the style done in a way that does not wrap divs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyhPI.png)

To achieve this, I created a box with position absolute which overlays a line with position fixed, then used the z-index to place the box over the line [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW5C9.png). The box has the same color as the background. When you scroll, the box which is in absolute position will move, but the fixed line which has the height of the screen continues to span the full screen. This means that while you scroll, the line is "revealed" from behind the box, giving the illusion that the line starts from a specific position and spans to the end of the page.

My code:

```css
/* create box to cover line */
.box {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;

    left: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* line set as 100% height and fixed, when scrolling boxCover will move to show line */
.line {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: column;
    left: 60px;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
  
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

/* divs of the rest of the page can be adjusted with z-index */
.page-divs {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: have you try `height: calc(100vh - 300px)` for your line height?

Comment: I tried it, but that wouldn't make the line extend to the bottom of the page, only the bottom of the viewport. I need it to start from a specific position, and end at the end of the page.

I came up with a workaround which I edited in above post; it's not perfect, but it gets the job done!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work for you as well.

```js
window.onload = function (){
            var line = document.getElementById('line');
        const  page_height = document.body.clientHeight;
        line.style.height = (page_height - 300)+'px';
}
```

```css
.static {
         overflow: hidden;
         position: absolute;
         flex-direction: column;
         left: 100px;
         top: 300px;
         border-left: 3px solid red; 
    }
```